# The probability of double chance being a good or bad virus when killing a virus and automatically double itself every time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

This is a question I read somewhere else and think so much about getting an answer, but still struggling. Here is the problem:

I have 9 virus which is 5 of them are good, and 4 of them are bad. Every time I kill a virus, it dies, and 2 viruses will be born from its body which is having 50-50 chances to be a good or bad virus.

What is the probability that after 100 times I kill a virus randomly and the amount of bad virus is zero? Which probability formula or theory should I learn to solve this one? Thanks.

Comment: Do you pick the virus to be killed randomly, or can you specifically target bad viruses?

Comment: The virus is picked randomly. You know exactly which is a bad or good virus after it was born.

Comment: The probability is extremely small.  At the last death, even if no bad viruses remain, you need two goods ones to be born (probability $\frac14.$)  If one bad virus remains, you have to pick it (probability ${1\over108}$) and then have two goods ones born.  You could try to program this, working backwards to the start, but eventually you'd be adding up a bunch of very small floating point numbers, and roundoff would make the program output essentially a random number.  (I ran thousands of simulations, and never had a success.)

Comment: I've coded this question on Python before, but I would like to know how to do it in a mathematical way with formula and the right approach.